# U is a subspace of $R^3$ which is spanned by $v$, write vector $u$ as a sum of $ x = x_1 + x_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

U is a subspace of $R^3$ which is spanned by $(1, 1, -2)^T$, write vector $(2 , 1 
, 3)^T $ as a sum of $ x = x_1 + x_2$, where $x_1 ∈ U$ and $x_2 ∈ U^⊥$

I know that $U^⊥$ is spanned by $a(2, 0 , 1 )^T + b(-1, 1 , 0)^T$

I thought I was supposed to solve this: $(2 , 1 ,3)^T = (1, 1 ,-2)^T + a(2, 0 ,1)^T +b(-1, 1, 0)^T$

But I didn't find a solution so I guess I'm not even close.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the orthogonal projection onto $U$?

Answer (score 3):

No, you have $(2 , 1 ,3)^T = c(1, 1 ,-2)^T + a(2, 0 ,1)^T +b(-1, 1, 0)^T$.

Now determine $a,b$ and $c$ via the system

$2=c+2a-b$

$1=c+b$

$3=-2c+a$

Comment: Ah I see, so $c=-1/2$ and $b=3/2$ and $a=2$. If I understood the question correctly that's my answer